# mysql query in php evaluates to true wrongly

Tags: php, mysql

somewhere I'm doing something wrong, my query results to true instead of false.  In my table the id 246 does exist but the lev is zero in the table.  What am I doing wrong, this query should result to false.  It echo's success but it does not update the table.

```
if (mysql_query("UPDATE ex_usrs SET lev = '1' WHERE id = '246' AND lev = '3'")) {
echo "success";
} else {
echo "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a
>   SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows
>   were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.

Don't use `mysql_query` to check if you really did update some rows. Use `mysql_affected_rows()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

It returns true because query was successfull and it affects 0 rows. If you want to check if something actually gets updated use

```
mysql_affected_rows
```

[link to documentation](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything wrong: `mysql_query` statement returns true because it is executed correctly!
This does not mean that any row gets updated in your database.

Comment: Ok thank you I understand now.  I was under the impression it returns true when the records were updated.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like the query is running, but not making any changes. As others have noted, this is the expected behavior.

You also said that lev is zero for the record with id 246. This explains why the update is failing. You are only updating the record with id 246 if lev is already set to 3. Depending on your situation, either of the following may work better for you:

```
if (mysql_query("UPDATE ex_usrs SET lev = '1' WHERE id = '246' AND lev = '0'")) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

or just ignore the current state lev completely:

```
if (mysql_query("UPDATE ex_usrs SET lev = '1' WHERE id = '246'")) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```